# Laravel polymorphic relation with custom key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my project I'm working on multiple databases and one central one. 
I'm using spatie's activity log package to log actions done form control panel to all of that databases.

I have table Items in each of the databases (except for the central) with auto incremented primary key, and another index called hash, which is kind of uuid. Hash is always unique.

Now, when I want to log actions, I can encounter problem as it will save ID of Item, so... in my activity tables I will get two records for subject_id = 1, while one activity happend to Item on one db and another on another, and so on.

How can I change set morphing to use my uuid column instead of id without changing $primaryKey on related model?

Item model relation:

```php
public function activities(): MorphMany
{
    $this->morphMany(Activity::class, 'subject', 'subject_id', 'hash');
}
```

Activity model relation:

```php
public function subject(): MorphTo
{
    if (config('activitylog.subject_returns_soft_deleted_models')) {
        return $this->morphTo()->withTrashed();
    }
    return $this->morphTo('activity_log', 'subject_type', 'subject_id', 'hash');
}
```

Also, I found in ActivityLogger:

```php
public function performedOn(Model $model)
{
    $this->getActivity()->subject()->associate($model);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation. You can pass a second, third, and sometimes fourth parameter to the relationship methods to override id, foreign_id and table names.

Comment: You can set additional params in [`morphTo`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_morphTo). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I know, however it doesn't seem to change anything. On my custom activity model I did: 
`$this->morphTo('activity_log', 'subject_type', 'subject_id', 'hash');`

And relation in model: `$this->morphMany(Activity::class, 'subject', 'subject_id', 'hash');`

Comment: In that case, can you add your Model code into the question. That way someone will be able to help you. I would suggest trimming them down to just the bare minimum (class Name and relationship methods).

Comment: @Jeemusu – added ;-)

Comment: The default morphMany takes the following parameters: `morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null)`. Yours should probably be `morphMany(Activity::class, 'subject', 'subject_type', 'subject_id', 'hash');`

Comment: I am not sure if relation defined on Item model matters right now, anyway – Activity is still saved using Item ID instead of hash :(

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir – 5.8

Comment: Your `MorphTo` relationship is correct. This is actually a bug in Laravel. I'll work on a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with temporary hack.

First of all, I've added a public method to my model:

```php
public function setPrimaryKey(string $columnName)
{
    $this->primaryKey = $columnName;
    $this->keyType = 'string';
}
```

Later on I extended ActivityLogger class and implemented my own `perfomedOn()` method.

```php
public function performedOn(Model $model)
{
    if($model instanceof Item::class) {
        $model->setPrimaryKey('hash');
    }

    return parent::performedOn($model);
}
```

I am aware it is not the best solution but kind of works for now.